# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache' in Apache using Python3

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm having trouble running my Django application through Apache. Running Django on the built in development server works fine, as does serving html files directly through Apache.

I originally had the error 'no module named django.core.wsgi' which I remedied by updating the WSGIPythonHome directive to point to the python3.6/site-packages directory.

After doing this from looking at the traceback the server appears able to locate django.core.wsgi but now throws the error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

I read it could potentially be a Python2 / Python3 issue with Apaches version of mod_wsgi so I reconfigured Apache and reran make, make install but no luck there.

I found the same question posted here:
[AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609614/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-lru-cache)

and tried the recommended solution of removing libapache2-mod-wsgi and installing libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 both system wide and within the virtual environment I'm pointing to in my httpd.conf file. This didn't fix the issue either.

What could be the cause ?

Help is greatly appreciated !

Full traceback:

```
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085731 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085749 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]   File "/WEBPAGE/myproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085771 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085779 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]   File "/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085790 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]     from django.utils.version import get_version, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085796 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]   File "/WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 71, in <module>, referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085806 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174]     @functools.lru_cache(), referer: http://127.0.1.1/
[Sat Jun 06 10:00:57.085819 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 14226:tid 139691700082432] [client 127.0.0.1:60174] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache', referer: http://127.0.1.1/
```

httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 80

Include ./conf/MODULES

<IfModule unixd_module>

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">

    #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted

</Directory>

Alias /static /WEBPAGE/static

<Directory /WEBPAGE/static>
    require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /WEBPAGE/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

#WSGIDaemonprocess myproject python-path=/WEBPAGE python-home=/WEBPAGE
#WSGIProcessGroup myproject

WSGIScriptAlias / /WEBPAGE/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /WEBPAGE/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```